# What Happens If I Detach A Thread That Has Been Joined?

Tags: c, multithreading

Question is fairly self explanatory, but here is the context, basically I have a server socket thread that spawns child threads when it receives new connections. These child threads accept data dumps from the remote connections, then clean up themselves and close when they are done.

Currently I have the child threads calling "pthread_detach(pthread_self())" right before they exit, what I'm considering doing is making the program to wait on program close, for the active data dumps to finish. Now I actually already have an alternate way around this that's part of the dynamic array I'm using to keep track of the active threads, but for future reference I would like to know what would happen if you joined a thread destined to detach itself before it closes and if it'll cause any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the documentation says.

*If an implementation detects use of a thread ID after the end of its lifetime, it is recommended that the function should fail and report an [ESRCH] error.* ( Is listed for both functions. )

If you join a detached thread you should get an error returned.

The same happens if you detach a joined thread.

Comment: So, I assume would that mean that detaching the thread would invalidate the thread ID, which would make the joined thread throw the error?

Comment: Something like that. The function would try to find the id and fail.

Comment: That would mean the implementation of pthread_join would have keep checking the id after the initial call, which would make sense because if the id did become invalidated then the data it pointed too would also be invalid, resulting in a null pointer or something similar. So in theory you could still join to a thread you knew was going to detach, but you would be expecting a [ESRCH] error rather then a return value, thanks.

Comment: @Skid I would rather use a container and some flags.

Comment: That is the plan, I have a Dynamic Pool (array) with the following struct in them I'm going to be using.
"typedef struct
{
 pthread_t worker;
 bool used;
} Element;"
So each worker will just be setting the used variable to false when it closes. I wanted to know what the effect would be for future reference so I knew what would happen if I came across something like this again.